# QuickBlox - can't connect to chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

When my app starts, I am using QMServicesManager to:

```
- (void)logInWithUser:(QBUUser *)user
```

This should take care of authentication and logging in to the chat service.
The login API call to the chat service returns without an error but I am still getting an error once I try to send a message:

"You are not connected to chat."

Calling `[QBChat instance]).isConnected` returns `false`

At that point, if I try to to resolve this by calling QMChatService:

```
- (void)connectWithCompletionBlock:(QBChatCompletionBlock)completion
```

I get an error: `"Attempting to connect while already connected or connecting."`

**Update:** 
Using extended logs of QuickBlox I can see where this begins. logging in to the chat service actually fails without returning any error in the return block.
Here is the log:

```
23:07:12.982 [ChatService] Connecting to Chat, host: chat.quickblox.com, user JID: ...
23:07:42.983 [ChatService] Did disconnect
```

Looks like it's timing out...
Any insights about that?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `[QBSettings setLogLevel: QBLogLevelDebug];` when application starts in the AppDelegate.

This would enable you to see the QuickBlox Log in your Xcode console which will give a better message about what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good advice. Updated my question with more info based on the data from the extended logs.